# Removing duplicate entries from a Mysql database

Tags: mysql

I've got a table with three columns, obj1, obj2 (both varchars) and the distance between the objects. Unfortunately the way the data was constructed, I've double the number of entries, for example,

```
obj1      obj2       distance
c1        c2         10.5
c2        c1         10.5
```

Want I want is to be able to delete one of the entries listed. I've thought and tried to use the Exists clause, but had no luck. I'm wondering if this requires a stored procedure?

Any help would be gratefully received!
Jim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can guarantee that every row has a "duplicate" with obj1 and obj2 values reversed, then you can remove one such row for each duplicate by doing

```
DELETE FROM dist WHERE obj1 > obj2
```

where `dist` is the name of your table.

If your table has rows where `obj1` equals `obj2`, then you could make a unique index on (obj1,obj2):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE dist ADD UNIQUE INDEX dist_index (obj1,obj2)
```

The above command will drop rows from the table whenever the unique index constraint is not satisfied. (The first row where obj1 equals obj2, the row will be kept because the unique index constraint is still satisfied. The second row where obj1 equals obj2 will be dropped, because the second row contradicts the uniqueness constraint.)

You can choose to keep the unique index, or, if you wish to drop it, the command would be:

```
ALTER TABLE dist DROP INDEX dist_index
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> create table doubles(a int,b int,c int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into doubles values (1,2,10),(2,1,10),(1,3,12),(3,1,12),(2,3,13);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from doubles;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |   10 |
|    2 |    1 |   10 |
|    1 |    3 |   12 |
|    3 |    1 |   12 |
|    2 |    3 |   13 |
+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELETE a FROM doubles a JOIN doubles b ON a.a = b.b AND a.b = b.a AND a.a > b.a;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from doubles;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |   10 |
|    1 |    3 |   12 |
|    2 |    3 |   13 |
+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The last clause (`a.a > b.a`) could equally be `a.a < b.a`, we just have to decide which one of the doubles should go.

Comment: Having problems making this work, I've tried to play with this, eventually getting to

Comment: Sorry accidentally pressed return.ysql> delete  FROM spectramatches_2 as sa JOIN  spectramatches_2 as sb ON sa.spectra1 = sb.spectra2 AND sa.spectra2 = sb.spectra1 AND sa.spectra1 > sb.spectra1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as sa JOIN  spectramatches_2 as sb ON sa.spectra1 = sb.spectra2 AND sa.spectra2 ' at line 1

Comment: The Table definition is mysql> describe spectramatches_2
    -> ;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| core1         | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| distance_c1s1 | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| spectra1      | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| distance_s1s2 | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| spectra2      | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| distance_c2s2 | double

Comment: Notice the alias a being _between_ `DELETE` & `FROM`, would be: `DELETE sa FROM spectramatches_2 as sa JOIN spectramatches_2 as sb ON sa.spectra1 = sb.spectra2 AND sa.spectra2 = sb.spectra1 AND sa.spectra1 > sb.spectra1;`